# Handling VSIX Toolwindow visibility events during 'Edit' and 'Debugging' layout changes

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-extensions, vsix, vspackage

I have a Visual Studio toolwindow that implements IVsWindowFrameNotify3, and I can successfully track when the Window is being moved, shown or hidden during 'normal window operations' via user interaction.

However when I run a loaded project the ToolWindow gets closed (hidden) and none of the IVsWindowFrameNotify3 methods get raised.

I'd like to prevent my toolwindow from being closed whilst debugging.

What events should I be listening to that will allow me to override the window closure whilst Visual Studio isn't exiting?

** UPDATE **

To an extent, the question is wrong, and shows my lack of understanding on how Visual Studio works.

Visual Studio uses 'layouts' which change depending on the mode Visual Studio is running in.  So, in effect, what I am seeing is a difference between the 'Editing' Layout and the 'Debugging' Layout, where the extension was shown in edit mode, but had not be shown in debugging mode.

Therefore in a way it's not up to my extension as to whether or not it should be hidden, but the users choice.

So, the question should really be 'How do I listen to when Visual Studio changes the layout mode before raising events with my extension'.

This could become an important question for my extension, as it should free up resources during debugging and will therefore need to listen to events when it's closed by a layout change.  (It's fine if the user choses to have the extension open in the Debugging layout).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With pair programming working at it's best on Discord, two of us devised a 'better' way of resolving this.

At first we tried to bind to the Windows Forms Control VisibleChanged event (as the component we're interested in is embedded in a WindowsFormHost WPF control).  That didn't work so well.

However, binding to the WPF control's IsVisibleChanged changed worked as you'd expect.

So the answer is, don't rely on Visual Studio in all instances for notifications!